# Outlook 2016 - Can "mark as read" be completely disabled?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I already have turned off automatic "Mark as read" by following the instructions at [Do not automatically mark as read](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/250)

Is there a way to completely disable any and all automatic "Mark as read", even if you double click the message to open it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not realizable in Outlook to completely disable "Mark as read" even when you double click to open the email.
Why you want to keep messages unread?

Comment: My colleague go trough his list of emails and decide then which email need to be answered first. But in the end he lose track of what he allready had done.

Comment: If a message was replied, we may see a message in the Infobar: "You replied to this message on..." In my opinion, he can also add flags to emails that he haven't replied as a workaround.